# Why do I get "?" marks for the citations inside my LaTeX output?

Tags: bibtex

I have made a `.bib` file named `myreferences.bib` using JabRef software and I have imported it into my `.tex` file named `mypaper.tex` through the following line:

```
\bibliography{myreferences}
```

at the end of `mypaper.tex` file just after the following line:

```
\bibliographystyle{mnras}
```

and just before the following lines:

```
\bsp
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

And below are all the lines appearing in the beginning of `mypaper.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

Prior to today, I never had problem updating `myreferences.bib` file and compiling `mypaper.tex` file. However starting today, I just noticed that all the citations in the output are marked with a **?** mark for any newly added reference into `myreferences.bib` file. The first thing I did was to disable the firewall of my antivirus and then update MikTeX program and then enabled the firewall. (I did this because in updating MikTeX I was receiving error messages before disabling firewall). After updating MikTex, I enabled my antivirus firewall back again. But the issue is still not resolved. Your help is greatly appreciated.

---

Here is a Minimal Working Example:

> mypaper.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\title[]{The Title of the Paper}

\author[A. Lastname et al.]{
Andrew Smith,$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: asmith@caltech.edu}
Andrea Robertson,$^{2}$\thanks{E-mail: arobetrson@as.arizona.edu}
Asher Aaronson$^{2,3}$\thanks{E-mail: aaronson@email.arizona.edu}
\\
$^{2}$Department of Astronomy/Steward Observatory, University of Arizona, 933 North Cherry Avenue, Tucson, AZ 85721, USA\\
$^{3}$Department of Physics and Atmospheric Sciences, University of Arizona, 2381 E. Fourth Street, Phoenix, AZ 85721, USA\\
$^{1}$California Institute of Technology, 1600 East California Blvd, Pasadena, CA 91125, USA}

\date{Accepted XXX. Received YYY; in original form ZZZ}

\pubyear{2016}
\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}
     \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Figure4}
    \caption{This is taken from \citet{2016arXiv160608440M} and \citet{2016ApJ...824..110C}.}
    \label{fig:Figure 4}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{myreferences2}

\appendix
\bsp    
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

> myreferences2.bib file: (I am including only those two new references that are problematic. That's why I created a second .bib file which includes only these two new references.)

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{2016ApJ...824..110C,
  author =        {{Crone Odekon}, M. and {Koopmann}, R.~A. and {Haynes}, M.~P. and {Finn}, R.~A. and {McGowan}, C. and {Micula}, A. and {Reed}, L. and {Giovanelli}, R. and {Hallenbeck}, G.},
  title =         {{The HI Content of Galaxies in Groups and Clusters as Measured by ALFALFA}},
  journal =       {\apj},
  year =          {2016},
  volume =        {824},
  pages =         {110},
  month =         jun,
  adsnote =       {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl =        {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016ApJ...824..110C},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi =           {10.3847/0004-637X/824/2/110},
  eid =           {110},
  eprint =        {1604.08862},
  file =          {:2016ApJ...824..110C.pdf:PDF},
  keywords =      {galaxies: clusters: general, galaxies: evolution, galaxies: groups: general, galaxies: ISM, galaxies: spiral, galaxies: statistics }
}

@Article{2016arXiv160608440M,
  author =        {{Martindale}, H. and {Thomas}, P.~A. and {Henriques}, B.~M. and {Loveday}, J.},
  title =         {{A consistent model for both the HI and stellar mass functions of galaxies}},
  journal =       {ArXiv e-prints},
  year =          {2016},
  month =         jun,
  adsnote =       {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl =        {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016arXiv160608440M},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eprint =        {1606.08440},
  file =          {2016arXiv160608440M.pdf:2016arXiv160608440M.pdf:PDF;:2016arXiv160608440M.pdf:PDF},
  keywords =      {Astrophysics - Astrophysics of Galaxies}
}
```

And the output, namely Figure 4, with a caption is created successfully in the pdf fomrat. In the caption of the figure, all the writings are present except the actual cited articles `author et al. (year)` which appear as question marks "?" without quotes:

> This is taken from ? and ?.

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex` then `bibtex` then `pdflatex` then `pdflatex`? Did you receive any warnings from the `bibtex` run? Or errors or warnings from the `pdflatex` runs? We can't do much with fragments of code. Please provide a complete minimal example which can be used to reproduce the problem, including a sample `.bib` entry. Note that `ae` is deprecated.

Comment: I did all that. Nowhere I received any warnings. All steps runs smoothly. What do you mean by "ae"? Should it be different?

Comment: The package is deprecated. You may have done some bits of what I suggested, but you've not done the `complete minimal example` bit. If you don't even get warnings, though, I don't know what to tell you. That would be unheard of unless you've literally asked TeX to use question marks as labels, of course.

Comment: How do you run bibtex? a possibility would be that the fresh MikTeX does not know about the local tex directory.

Comment: I am using TexWorks software for producing the paper. myreferences.bib file is produced by JabRef. Then, opened by TexWorks side by side with mypaper.tex.  So, all I do to run myreferences.bib file, I choose "bibTeX" from the drop-down menu in a New page and then find my .bib file from "Open" and finally push the green button named "Typeset". This file is a long one with 2067 lines filled with bibTeX references of different papers. After running it, it doesn't give me any message.

Comment: A minimal working example has been created.

Comment: You don't typeset the `.bib` file. That's not the way it works. You typeset a `.tex` document which references your `.bib` file.

Comment: @cfr. I actually just made up those emails. They are not real. Sorry, how should I run .bib then?

Comment: BibTeX cannot handle UTF-8 encoding.  Your `.bib` seems designed for Biblatex, but you are not using Biblatex.

Comment: You typeset the `.tex` file e.g. `pdflatex <myfile>.tex`. Then you run `bibtex <myfile>`. Then you run `pdflatex` twice more.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's contribution towards understanding the problem. First thing I learned is the importance of the order of running scripts which should be as below: (As mentioned by username cfr)

```
1. Typsetting .tex file (e.g. pdfLatex mypaper.tex)
2. Running myreferences.bib file
3. Running pdfLatex
4. Running padfLatex
```

However, I was able to resolve the issue by these steps only after I removed all the intermediate and auxiliary files from the working directory (namely .bbl, .out, .synctex, .bib.bak, etc. leaving only two files `mypaper.tex` and `myreferences.bib` files; It seemed that older auxiliary files were interfering with updating `myreferences.bib` file.) 
I also had to add one more step to the above list which is:.

```
5. Running pdfLatex+makeIndex+bibTeX all three together as the final step
```